# Problem while reverse engineering file in ODI 12c

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to reverse engineer a csv file, so that I would use it to create an ODi mapping to load data from file to table. While doing reverse engineering under `Attributes` tab, I face the below error -

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: #PROJECT.DIRECTORY_PATH/#PROJECT.FILE_NAME
```

where `#PROJECT.DIRECTORY_PATH` is a project-specific variable to get the unix directory path where the file resides and `PROJECT.FILE_NAME` is a variable indicating the file name. Could anyone please help me find the cause of this error? TIA.

I tried validating the queries which I had used in the variable and they seem to fetch the correct results for the directory path and the file name.

Comment: Hi. Did you used a customized KM for reverse engineer? (RKM)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, I did not use any customized KN for reverse engineering. I am just trying to reverse engineer under the 'Attributes' tab of the datastore and encounter the error - java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: #PROJECT.DIRECTORY_PATH/#PROJECT.FILE_NAME . FYI , this file which I am trying to reverse engineer exists in the UNIX server path.

Comment: @Sara Did you find any solution to this problem? Im facing exactly this right now..

Answer (score 0):

try with the name of the file in clear. I think that you cannot use variables there!

Comment: I fear if I can hard-code the file name. Moreover, the file is not in my local and it resides in UNIX server, so I use the variable to fetch the file path and name using SQL query. Anyhow, to try what you recommended, I tested by mentioning the  UNIX-server-path\file-name in the 'Resource name' under 'Attributes' tab and still encounter the same error as java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:<UNIX-server-path>